# message sending in android

Tags: java, android, sms

to send a message in my application in android i have used the following code.

```
package wishme.code;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Activity2 extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancestate) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstancestate);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        Button previous=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_prev);
        Button send=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        EditText ph_no=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_phone);
        EditText msg=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_msg);

    }
    public void prevclickhandler(View view)
    {
        switch(view.getId())
        {
        case R.id.button_prev:
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
        finish();
        break;
        case R.id.button_send:
            **String ph_no= ph_no.getText().tostring();** 
    }}
}
```

But the line highlighted gives error that is
the method getText is undefined for the type string
how can i resolve this.

Comment: On a side note, you don't need to declare those Buttons and EditText variables in `onCreate` if you don't intend to modify them. The system creates and sets them up for you when it reads the XML file (during `setContentView`).  The `findViewById` function is just a way for you to reference already existing variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variables are defined in different scopes.  The ph_no EditText is defined in onCreate and not available in your click handler.  The ph_no you are actually calling getText() on is the String you are defining.

Instead, you can define the EditText inside your Activity as a instance variable and rename your String so the variable names don't collide.

Another approach is to just call findViewById when you need access to the EditText, like so:

```
String ph_no = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_phone)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: what i want is to access the variable EditText ph_no insidd my handler

Comment: If you find yourself writing that code a lot, you could make an instance variable that you could reference from all functions instead of having to do the findViewById every time.

Answer (score 1):

use the diffent name for for string

```
  String str_ph_no= ph_no.getText().tostring();
```

as local variable get preference so it will consider both "ph_no" as String

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this I think:

```
String ph_no_string = ph_no.getText().toString();
```

You first define ph_no as EditText, but later you redifine ph_no to a string.

Answer (score 0):

ph_no is not a defined local variable in our activity try this:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity{ 
private EditText ph_no;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancestate) {
    ...
    ph_no=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_phone);
    ...
```

And rename your String ph_no to something else like ph_no_string

Comment: what i want is to access the ph_no in my clickhandler.
i have tried the thing you are saying but get same result.